# LangChain "ChatOpenAI" LLM exceeding token length when using RetrievalQA to answer multiple questions

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am using Langchain to build a simple application that answers questions based on a provided document. I have implemented the following which works perfectly as a proof of concept:

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

embedding_client = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key)
embeddings = Chroma.from_texts([document_text], embedding_client)

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0, max_tokens=4096)
retriever = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm, retriever=embeddings.as_retriever())

answer = retriever({"query": question})
```

The issue is that if I ask multiple questions in a loop, after the second or third question I get a **context_length_exceeded** error from OpenAI. Even if it's the same question each time and each object is instantiated fresh in the loop:

```
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "This model's maximum context length is 16385 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 17725 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'messages', 'code': 'context_length_exceeded'}
```

It seems like either the chat history or the document itself is being re-used under the hood in the calls from the ChatOpenAI which is causing problems. I've played around with token limits but they don't seem to solve the core issue. Fundamentally, I expected creating a new instance of `ChatOpenAI` for each question should do the trick

I'm hoping someone can explain what is happening and how I can avoid exceeding this limit if I have no need for chat history. Preferably without making the implementation too much more complex! Thank you!

Comment: To see the prompt that is sent to the LLM, you can add `verbose=True` flag in the `from_chain_type` call. `retriever = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm, retriever=embeddings.as_retriever(), verbose=True)`. What is in the prompt when you run this?

Comment: Thanks Roland! Setting the verbosity flag got me a bit more info but I don't see the prompt itself:
```
> Entering new RetrievalQA chain...
Number of requested results 4 is greater than number of elements in index 2, updating n_results = 2

> Finished chain.
```
Even if I set it on the LLM I don't see the actual prompt

Comment: However, setting `retriever=embeddings.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1})` does seem to help, although I'm new to this and not sure if I'm not solving the core issue

Comment: That will reduce the number of documents to send to LLM as context, which will help contain the token count. However this also means there are less text being sent to the model as context.

Comment: From the logs it seems you only have two documents in the index. You might want to split the documents up before you index them, so that you can send more concise and relevant information to the model. Check this out: https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/chroma

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks that helps. Yeah so eventually I may run into the same issue. I'm reducing the context supplied, but things are likely still "adding up" under the hood so to speak

Comment: @Topazoo, I am currently facing the same issue with AzureChatOpenAI. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Hoping someone will know though!